# jQuery - Fire change event onload

Tags: jquery

I've a question related to a select element and jquery.
I currently have a change event so the changeShippingForm function gets called when the select element value has been changed, this is working just fine.

But I also want the change event fired at onload. How can I achieve this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#shippingType').change(changeShippingForm);
});

function changeShippingForm() {
   // do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use [`.trigger()`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#shippingType').change(changeShippingForm).trigger('change');
});
```

or even shorter, use the shortcut:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#shippingType').change(changeShippingForm).change();
});
```